# Calling ".class" on Typed class (e.g. MyClass<MyType>.class)

Tags: java, android, greenrobot-eventbus

I am trying to use a function in GreenRobot's `EventBus` class:

```
public <T> T removeStickyEvent(@NotNull Class<T> tClass);
```

This works with normal classes such as:

```
MyEvent myEvent = eventbus.removeStickyEvent(MyEvent.class);
```

---

Now, I would like to get away from defining classes that just hold a single object (e.g. `MyStringEvent`, `MyIntegerEvent`) and use generics (e.g. `MyEvent<String>`, `MyEvent<Integer>`). However, the following code no longer works:

```
// Error: 'Cannot select from parameterized type'
MyEvent<String> myStringEvent = eventBus.removeStickyEvent(MyEvent<String>.class);
```

---

**Is there a proper way to handle this use case?**